# How to withdraw DAI from DSR (Oasis Saving Dapp / MakerDao) using the contract only, not the Dapp frontend?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, dai, makerdao

I am currently testing the Oasis Saving Dapp by MakerDao (https://oasis.app/save). After converting some DAI to DSR, users can earn savings and whenever they want, withdraw their funds (convert back to DAI) using the Dapp front-end withdraw button.

I like the idea but before sending more DAI, I would like to figure out how to interact with the contract without using the frontend.

**Can someone tell me how to withdraw all savings using the contract code only ?** So not using the Oasis frontend. I'd like to know which function(s) do I need to call and what to fill as inputs.

Here is the contract code as deployed on savers' accounts :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract DSAuthority {
    function canCall(
        address src, address dst, bytes4 sig
    ) public view returns (bool);
}

contract DSAuthEvents {
    event LogSetAuthority (address indexed authority);
    event LogSetOwner     (address indexed owner);
}

contract DSAuth is DSAuthEvents {
    DSAuthority  public  authority;
    address      public  owner;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        emit LogSetOwner(msg.sender);
    }

    function setOwner(address owner_)
        public
        auth
    {
        owner = owner_;
        emit LogSetOwner(owner);
    }

    function setAuthority(DSAuthority authority_)
        public
        auth
    {
        authority = authority_;
        emit LogSetAuthority(authority);
    }

    modifier auth {
        require(isAuthorized(msg.sender, msg.sig));
        _;
    }

    function isAuthorized(address src, bytes4 sig) internal view returns (bool) {
        if (src == address(this)) {
            return true;
        } else if (src == owner) {
            return true;
        } else if (authority == DSAuthority(0)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return authority.canCall(src, this, sig);
        }
    }
}

contract DSNote {
    event LogNote(
        bytes4   indexed  sig,
        address  indexed  guy,
        bytes32  indexed  foo,
        bytes32  indexed  bar,
        uint              wad,
        bytes             fax
    ) anonymous;

    modifier note {
        bytes32 foo;
        bytes32 bar;

        assembly {
            foo := calldataload(4)
            bar := calldataload(36)
        }

        emit LogNote(msg.sig, msg.sender, foo, bar, msg.value, msg.data);

        _;
    }
}

// DSProxy
// Allows code execution using a persistant identity This can be very
// useful to execute a sequence of atomic actions. Since the owner of
// the proxy can be changed, this allows for dynamic ownership models
// i.e. a multisig
contract DSProxy is DSAuth, DSNote {
    DSProxyCache public cache;  // global cache for contracts

    constructor(address _cacheAddr) public {
        require(setCache(_cacheAddr));
    }

    function() public payable {
    }

    // use the proxy to execute calldata _data on contract _code
    function execute(bytes _code, bytes _data)
        public
        payable
        returns (address target, bytes32 response)
    {
        target = cache.read(_code);
        if (target == 0x0) {
            // deploy contract & store its address in cache
            target = cache.write(_code);
        }

        response = execute(target, _data);
    }

    function execute(address _target, bytes _data)
        public
        auth
        note
        payable
        returns (bytes32 response)
    {
        require(_target != 0x0);

        // call contract in current context
        assembly {
            let succeeded := delegatecall(sub(gas, 5000), _target, add(_data, 0x20), mload(_data), 0, 32)
            response := mload(0)      // load delegatecall output
            switch iszero(succeeded)
            case 1 {
                // throw if delegatecall failed
                revert(0, 0)
            }
        }
    }

    //set new cache
    function setCache(address _cacheAddr)
        public
        auth
        note
        returns (bool)
    {
        require(_cacheAddr != 0x0);        // invalid cache address
        cache = DSProxyCache(_cacheAddr);  // overwrite cache
        return true;
    }
}

// DSProxyFactory
// This factory deploys new proxy instances through build()
// Deployed proxy addresses are logged
contract DSProxyFactory {
    event Created(address indexed sender, address indexed owner, address proxy, address cache);
    mapping(address=>bool) public isProxy;
    DSProxyCache public cache = new DSProxyCache();

    // deploys a new proxy instance
    // sets owner of proxy to caller
    function build() public returns (DSProxy proxy) {
        proxy = build(msg.sender);
    }

    // deploys a new proxy instance
    // sets custom owner of proxy
    function build(address owner) public returns (DSProxy proxy) {
        proxy = new DSProxy(cache);
        emit Created(msg.sender, owner, address(proxy), address(cache));
        proxy.setOwner(owner);
        isProxy[proxy] = true;
    }
}

// DSProxyCache
// This global cache stores addresses of contracts previously deployed
// by a proxy. This saves gas from repeat deployment of the same
// contracts and eliminates blockchain bloat.

// By default, all proxies deployed from the same factory store
// contracts in the same cache. The cache a proxy instance uses can be
// changed.  The cache uses the sha3 hash of a contract's bytecode to
// lookup the address
contract DSProxyCache {
    mapping(bytes32 => address) cache;

    function read(bytes _code) public view returns (address) {
        bytes32 hash = keccak256(_code);
        return cache[hash];
    }

    function write(bytes _code) public returns (address target) {
        assembly {
            target := create(0, add(_code, 0x20), mload(_code))
            switch iszero(extcodesize(target))
            case 1 {
                // throw if contract failed to deploy
                revert(0, 0)
            }
        }
        bytes32 hash = keccak256(_code);
        cache[hash] = target;
    }
}
```

Source : https://etherscan.io/address/0xad01c274961a55a493991e1f63e0c362aabf6705#code

When clicking the withdraw button on the Dapp, it seems the `execute()` function is called but I don't get what are `bytes _data`. Metamask shows a very long input (228 bytes) for this parameter but I don't get what it means and how one could guess it by himself if needed. Does someone know what to call exactly and what to fill as inputs ?

As a decentralized application, it would be very useful if for any reason the frontend is unavailable (maintenance, update...) and one wants his funds back.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

> but I don't get what are `bytes _data`

It's an encoded function-call, which is executed (via assembly) inside function `execute`.

Here is an example of an encoded function-call:

```
bytes4 selector = bytes4(uint256(keccak256("someFunc(address,uint256,bool)") >> 224));
bytes memory data = abi.encodeWithSelector(selector, someAddress, someUint256, someBool);
```

Of course, the encoding above is performed in the on-chain (inside a contract), while you need to compute the same thing in the off-chain (e.g., in a web3.js script), and then pass it to the contract's function.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. Ok I will try to take a closer look at the encoded function calls. So it seems a bit fastidious to call an emergency exit smoothly. As a dapp with more than 50M$ locked, i thought it would have been easier.

Answer (score 0):

What in case the oasis website disappears? Are my coins at risk because they are delegated into a difficult contract?

Thats why I also would like to know how I can withdraw my savings using the contract code only.

From the answer above it seems complicated, I have no idea how to generate that data field. Maybe can someone do a step-by-step description for MEW contract interaction to withdraw from the oasis DSR contract?